# Continuous Delivery, Versioning and Feature Branches confusion

Tags: continuous-delivery, branching-strategy

I'm currently in the process of implementing CD with a Feature Branch Workflow. What's unclear to me is when to increase the version number.

Shall it be increased when a new feature is created?

So let's say we have version 1.1 and I'm going to implement a new feature FB-123.

When creating the FB shall I increment the version?

> ```
>        *---*--- increment build number, now on 1.2.456 
>       / increment version to 1.2 
>   ---* 1.1
> ```

And use the Jenkins Build number for subsequent commits?

Comment: It all really depends on who the build number is for. Is it for you internally to help resolve this back to a commit? Is this for other techies to see, thus they can infer what's changing from the semantics of the build number? This is worth a read - http://semver.org/ to give you some food for thought

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd Yes it's for resolving it back. I don't really mind if it's semantic or not.

Comment: do you use git? what does happen with a feature branch when it is been finished? Do you merge it back to the master or to release branch?

Comment: @YuriG. At the end a pull request is made and if accepted its merged into master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider to use the following versioning schema:

- Every major/minor release is tagged with a `git` tag
- branches schema - `<major>.<minor>.<number of commits from latest minor>-<feature branch-name>-<sha1>`
- master schema - `<major>.<minor>` (it considers that every accepted pull request is a minor release)

You can calculate the number of commits from latest minor by

```
git rev-list HEAD ^<latest minor tag> --ancestry-path <latest minor tag> --count
```

This schema will allow you to derive from the version name:

- the base version
- the branch name
- the git commit that the version was built from
- to compare properly 2 versions of the same branch